# Unable to use LDAP Authentication with JupyterHub: Broken Pipe error

Tags: ldap, jupyterhub

I set up and LDAP Server using Docker (https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) as well as installed Jupyterhub on the same machine. Unfortunately, the connection between LDAP-Server and JupyterHub is not working. These are the lines corresponding to the LDAP Authentication in `jupyterhub_config.py`:

```
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'ldapauthenticator.LDAPAuthenticator'
c.LDAPAuthenticator.server_address = '192.168.48.2' # Docker Container IP of openldap
c.LDAPAuthenticator.lookup_dn = True
c.LDAPAuthenticator.use_ssl = False
# c.LDAPAuthenticator.bind_dn_template = ["cn={username},dc=example,dc=com"]
```

(Switching between the last two lines makes no difference.)

When I try to login at JupyterHub login page the follow error pops up:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketSendError: socket sending error[Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I can "access" the LDAP Database from command-line using ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.48.2 -b dc=example,dc=com -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w password
```

Disabling Firewall also makes no difference (was thinking about some network problems between Docker(openldap) and jupyterhub).

```
jupyterhub==1.1.0
jupyterhub-ldapauthenticator==1.3.2
```

I was able to reproduce this problem with `ldap3` outside of JupyterHub:

```
# Get IP of dockerized OpenLDAP
import docker
client = docker.DockerClient()
container = client.containers.get("openldap")
ip_add = container.attrs['NetworkSettings']['Networks']['ldap_default']['IPAddress']

# Check Connection
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
server = Server(ip_add,use_ssl=False,port=389)
conn = Connection(server)
print(conn.bind(read_server_info=True))

> True
```

When I now replace `ssl=False` with `ssl=True` it returns the same error as with JupyterHub:

```
# Check Connection
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
server = Server(ip_add,use_ssl=True,port=636
conn = Connection(server)
print(conn.bind(read_server_info=True))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_connection.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(conn.bind(read_server_info=True))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 590, in bind
    response = self.post_send_single_response(self.send('bindRequest', request, controls))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 330, in send
    self.sending(ldap_message)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 882, in sending
    raise communication_exception_factory(LDAPSocketSendError, type(e)(str(e)))(self.connection.last_error)
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketSendError: socket sending error[Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

It seems that this has something to do with SSL/TLS/StartTLS. If I disable `ssl` in the `jupyterhub_config.py` the Authenticator will (try) to upgrade with StartTLS.

> LDAPAuthenticator.use_ssl
>
> Boolean to specify whether to use SSL encryption when contacting the
> LDAP server. If it is left to False (the default) LDAPAuthenticator
> will try to upgrade connection with StartTLS. Set this to be True to
> start SSL connection.
> (URL: https://github.com/jupyterhub/ldapauthenticator :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

```
  c.LDAPAuthenticator.server_address= 'ldaps://192.168.48.2:636' or 'ladp://192.168.48.2:389'
```

636 and 389 being the default ports for ldaps and ldap

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't work either. I moved the LDAP to a local installation instead of docker and everything works fine now.